# Vibrate with duration and pattern

Tags: java, android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, plugins

I am working on a simple plugin. Now I am trying to add a vibrate property. But this code is not working. Where am I going wrong? My code is as follows. Can you help me please.

**Android:**

import android.os.Vibrator;

```
public class Brid {

private Context context;
private static Brid instance;


public Brid()
{
    this.instance = this;
}

public static Brid instance()
{
    if(instance == null) {
        instance = new Brid();
    }
    return instance;
}

public void setContext(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}



public void Vibrate()
{
    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) this.context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    v.vibrate(100);
}
```

}

**Unity3D:**

```
    public static void Vibrate(AndroidJavaObject Brid, AndroidJavaObject context)
{
    if (Brid == null)
    {
        using (AndroidJavaClass activityClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
        {
            context = activityClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        }

        using (AndroidJavaClass pluginClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.xxx.ultimatemobile.Brid"))
        {
            if (pluginClass != null)
            {
                Brid = pluginClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("instance");
                Brid.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setContext", context);
                Brid.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("Vibrate");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Button Event:**

```
public void vibrate()
    {
#if UNITY_ANDROID

        Bridge.Vibrate(null, null);

#endif
    }
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Do you get any error from the log?

Comment: Check your manifest for `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />`

Comment: I only tried on Android. But application wasn't closed.

Comment: I have AndroidManifest.xml file in jar file. Do I need add AndroidManifest.xml file in plugins folder. I haven't more information about this. Can you explain how to do?

Comment: Best way is to unzip .apk file and check if this line exists in manifest. If not, try to add it to manifest in assets/plugins/android.

Comment: Ok. I will try.

Comment: It doesn't have to close. There should be a log when there is problem. This log will also [show](http://imgur.com/a/7yY4z) if this is a permission problem.

Comment: I getting Non-static void error.

Comment: I fixed errors. But now I need add permission. I tried this. But still I getting permission warning.How can I do this? Can you show me a manifest example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution as follows.

**Unity:**

```
        using (AndroidJavaClass pluginClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.xx.ultimatemobile.Brid"))
        {
            if (pluginClass != null)
            {
                Brid = pluginClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("instance");
                Brid.Call("setContext", context);
                context.Call("runOnUiThread", new AndroidJavaRunnable(() =>
                {
                    Brid.Call("Vibrate");
                }));
            }
        }
```

Also, I found Manifest.xml file example before 1 minute. Now the plugin is working.

Answer (score 5):

I see you have a solution. For those who don't want to use Java. You can do this from C# only.

1.Go to `<UnityInstallationDirecory>\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Apk`, Copy the `AndroidManifest.xml` file to your `<ProjectName>Assets\Plugins\Android`

2.Now open the copied Manifest file from `<ProjectName>Assets\Plugins\Android`  and add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>` to it. Save, Build and Run. If this is a permission problem, that should now be solved.

What your `AndroidManifest.xml` should look like(Unity 5.4):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.unity3d.player"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

    <application
    android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

You don't even need to write Java plugin for simple vibration. This can be done with Unity's AndroidJavaClass and AndroidJavaObject classes.

Complete Vibration Plugin without Java.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Vibrate
{

    public AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer;
    public AndroidJavaObject currentActivity;
    public AndroidJavaObject sysService;


    public void Vibrate()
    {
        unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
        currentActivity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        sysService = currentActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getSystemService", "vibrator");
    }

    //Functions from https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html
    public void vibrate()
    {
        sysService.Call("vibrate");
    }


    public void vibrate(long milliseconds)
    {
        sysService.Call("vibrate", milliseconds);
    }

    public void vibrate(long[] pattern, int repeat)
    {
        sysService.Call("vibrate", pattern, repeat);
    }


    public void cancel()
    {
        sysService.Call("cancel");
    }

    public bool hasVibrator()
    {
        return sysService.Call<bool>("hasVibrator");
    }
}
```

**[Usage](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html#vibrate(long[],%20int))**:

```
Vibrate vibrate = new Vibrate();

if (vibrate.hasVibrator())
{
    //Vibrate
    vibrate.vibrate();

    //Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
    vibrate.vibrate(500);

    // Start without a delay
    // Vibrate for 200 milliseconds
    // Sleep for 2000 milliseconds
    long[] pattern = { 0, 200, 2000 };
    vibrate.vibrate(pattern, 0);

    //Cancel Vibration
    vibrate.cancel();
}
```