# Do I have to add VIBRATE permission if I'm using Handheld.Vibrate()

Tags: unity-game-engine

Do I have to add VIBRATE permission if I'm using Handheld.Vibrate() or is it added automatically?

If I do have to add it, how do I do it. How to edit the AndroidManifest. This is in Unity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No**, you don't have to add it manually. The permission will be added by Unity automatically if you use `Handheld.Vibrate()`. The-same thing applies when you use other Unity API for sensors like camera, accelerometer, gyro and GPS.

> If I do have to add it, how do I do it. How to edit the
>   AndroidManifest

1.Go to `<UnityInstallationDirecory>\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Apk`, Copy the `AndroidManifest.xml` file to your `<ProjectName>Assets\Plugins\Android`

2.Now open the copied Manifest file from `<ProjectName>Assets\Plugins\Android`  and add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>` to it. Save, Build and Run.

But again, you don't have to add it manually.

Remember that [`Handheld.Vibrate()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Handheld.Vibrate.html) only do short vibration. If you need vibration with pattern, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39668630/3785314)

Comment: Very generous and fast answer. I made this question some hours ago in Unity Answers, didn't get an answer :p Thank you.

Comment: Unity Answers is not very well active. You are welcome!