# How to use Handheld.Vibrate() for a series of vibrations?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How to use Handheld.Vibrate() for more then one vibration?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39651021/unity3d-vibrate-android/39668630#39668630

Comment: **"Call me stupid but that is Java not C#. I asked " Can i do something like that just in C#?""** You may be indeed stupid because the answer I left on that post is in C# and that's the proper way to do Vibration pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can do what you want using Coroutines :

```
void OnGUI()
{
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(0, 10, 100, 32), "Vibrate!"))
        StartCoroutine( Vibrate() ) ;
}

private IEnumerator Vibrate()
{
     float interval = 0.05f ;
     WaitForSeconds wait = new WaitForSeconds(interval);
     float t ;

     for( t = 0 ; t < 1 ; t += interval ) // Change the end condition (t < 1) if you want
     {
         Handheld.Vibrate();
         yield return wait ;
     }

     yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.4f);

     for( t = 0 ; t < 1 ; t += interval ) // Change the end condition (t < 1) if you want
     {
         Handheld.Vibrate();
         yield return wait ;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hellium, i will try that.